# Linking source and library directories in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

It was 2 years since the last time I used C++. In the past I used VS2008 and everything was fine, now I just switched to VS2012 and it seems I can't config to use any of additional source and library directories, always getting LNK2001 and LNK2019 errors even though they are exact configs as I did with VS2008.

I'm sorry, I though images would help people checking if I set things up at the right place. VS2012 is quite confusing to me.

I have tried using Diluculum, here is my config in VS2012:
[image: Config Diluculum in VS2012]
[image: Config Diluculum in VS2012]

I'm not sure if my configs are right for this version of Visual Studio. I tried to find a way myself but it was 4 days already without any process to run a simple source. It's so depressing.

**Edit:**

The errors with Diluculum:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>moc_mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::LuaValue(void)" (??0LuaValue@Diluculum@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl Diluculum::`dynamic initializer for 'Nil''(void)" (??__ENil@Diluculum@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::LuaValue(void)" (??0LuaValue@Diluculum@@QAE@XZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::LuaValue(void)" (??0LuaValue@Diluculum@@QAE@XZ)
1>moc_mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::LuaValue(class std::map<class Diluculum::LuaValue,class Diluculum::LuaValue,struct std::less<class Diluculum::LuaValue>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class Diluculum::LuaValue const ,class Diluculum::LuaValue> > > const &)" (??0LuaValue@Diluculum@@QAE@ABV?$map@VLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@U?$less@VLuaValue@Diluculum@@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBVLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@@std@@@4@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl Diluculum::`dynamic initializer for 'EmptyTable''(void)" (??__EEmptyTable@Diluculum@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::LuaValue(class std::map<class Diluculum::LuaValue,class Diluculum::LuaValue,struct std::less<class Diluculum::LuaValue>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class Diluculum::LuaValue const ,class Diluculum::LuaValue> > > const &)" (??0LuaValue@Diluculum@@QAE@ABV?$map@VLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@U?$less@VLuaValue@Diluculum@@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBVLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@@std@@@4@@std@@@Z)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::LuaValue(class std::map<class Diluculum::LuaValue,class Diluculum::LuaValue,struct std::less<class Diluculum::LuaValue>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class Diluculum::LuaValue const ,class Diluculum::LuaValue> > > const &)" (??0LuaValue@Diluculum@@QAE@ABV?$map@VLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@U?$less@VLuaValue@Diluculum@@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBVLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@@std@@@4@@std@@@Z)
1>moc_mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::destroyObjectAtData(void)" (?destroyObjectAtData@LuaValue@Diluculum@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::_Wrap_alloc<class std::allocator<struct std::_Tree_node<struct std::pair<class Diluculum::LuaValue const ,class Diluculum::LuaValue>,void *> > >::destroy<struct std::pair<class Diluculum::LuaValue const ,class Diluculum::LuaValue> >(struct std::pair<class Diluculum::LuaValue const ,class Diluculum::LuaValue> *)" (??$destroy@U?$pair@$$CBVLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@@std@@@?$_Wrap_alloc@V?$allocator@U?$_Tree_node@U?$pair@$$CBVLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@@std@@PAX@std@@@std@@@std@@QAEXPAU?$pair@$$CBVLuaValue@Diluculum@@V12@@1@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::destroyObjectAtData(void)" (?destroyObjectAtData@LuaValue@Diluculum@@AAEXXZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall Diluculum::LuaValue::destroyObjectAtData(void)" (?destroyObjectAtData@LuaValue@Diluculum@@AAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\Win32\Release\\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Please don't add images when text would do, adding unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Actually the images are useful. It's more normal to put additional includes in "C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories" rather than in VC++ Directories like you have them. That's meant for 'system' includes, i.e. the Standard Library.

Comment: I'm sorry, I though images would help people checking if I set things up at the right place. VS2012 is quite confusing to me. I tried config in "C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories" too but still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are linking against static versions of a library. This means, that your have CRT included in these libraries. But CRT is different for different versions of Visual Studio. You can use static linkage only against versions compiled in exactly the same Visual Studio.

At the [SFML download page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/) there are packages for different versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail. But I directly link to the source code of Diluculum and for SFML I'm sure I was using VC++11 (2012) versions of its static library.

Comment: Update your question and include the exact error messages you get from the linker.

Comment: Doesn't look like problems with CRT or any configurations incompatibility. But I see that you defined `SFML_STATIC` macro while using dynamic versions of libraries. Make it consistent. Either remove the macro, or link against static versions: with `-s`  (release) or `-s-d` (debug) suffix.

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail! I'm such an airhead! It's fine with SFML now after I link to the -s versions. But I'm still getting errors with Diluculum, tried to place the source code of it directly to my project but the errors are still the same. Thank you very much for helping me editing my post.

Comment: Seems like you don't link Lua properly. Hard to tell something more from the logs.

Comment: After downloading LUA 5.2.3, I see both header and source files of it in src folder then I link both include and source directories to there instead of building it. Is it the right way to do? I will take more research now. Though I said thank you quite a lot but thank you again Mikhail!

Comment: Libraries are usually linked in a different way. You don't need to set anything in "Source Directories" setting. This directory is used to find files for debugging. You need only to specify include directory for `.h` files and library directory for `.lib` files. If you messed up includes, you will have compiler errors. But you have linker errors, so you failed in libraries. Make sure you specified all necessary .lib files in "Additional dependencies" setting.

Comment: I want to use LUA directly from its source code without building library so I though I would link the source directories to where it contains its source files, seems that I misunderstood it. I'm going to build static library and try to link it properly, hope it will help. I will take more research and doublecheck everything up carefully instead of asking more questions. I'm sorry for the troubles Mikhail.

Comment: When you use a library "from sources" you actually are doing the same, but Visual Studio can hide some steps from you if your library is included in your solution. However, it is not the way libraries are usually used. Many libraries contain many projects, so it is difficult to include them into your solution.